# All records by id eliminating duplicates within 30 days of two date columns, if any exist

Tags: mysql, window-functions

Given the following:

```
drop table if exists a;

create table a (
    id CHAR(30),
    d1 DATETIME,
    d2 DATETIME
);

insert into a values (1, '2012/1/1', '2012/1/2');
insert into a values (1, '2012/1/15', '2012/1/16');
insert into a values (1, '2012/1/25', '2012/1/26');
insert into a values (1, '2012/2/10', '2012/2/11');

insert into a values (2, '2012/1/1', '2012/1/2');
insert into a values (2, '2012/2/6', '2012/2/7');
```

I'd like to return all records for each ID, but eliminate any duplicates within 30 days (datediff(d2,d1) <= 30):

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | d1                  | d2                  |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1    | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | 2012-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 1    | 2012-02-10 00:00:00 | 2012-02-11 00:00:00 |
| 2    | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | 2012-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 2    | 2012-02-06 00:00:00 | 2012-02-07 00:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Since 1/15 and 1/25 were within 30 days of 1/1, they were removed. Hopefully that makes sense.  In a single select.

Comment: But how would you choose which of the two days to keep? Iterate over them in ascending order?

Comment: @Patash, yes, if I understand you.  In ascending order, once you have a record, any records within 30 days should be not appear in the result for that id.

Answer (score 0):

This query selects all rows that do not have a row with the same id 30 days or less earlier before them:

```
select * from table a a1
where not exists (select 1 from table a a2 where a2.id = a1.id
and (days(a1.d1) - days(a2.d1) < 30) and (days(a1.d1) > days(a2.d1))
```

The two parts of the subquery are: look for rows that are before us but not more than 30 days before us, if we find one reject this row.

Substitute your own sql flavour's date functions/date difference functions as needed

Comment: @Josh Unger You should either use an SQL datetime function for your sql flavour that 1) returns the number of days since the epoch, or 2) takes two dates and returns the day difference between them. Using such a function, it surely would work fine because it would be a huge, huge bug in the SQL flavour's function to not.

Comment: if you can provide a Sql Fiddle that works, I'd be glad to mark it as the answer.